# The return false in jquery each loop not end the entire function

Tags: javascript, jquery

It seems that the return word in jquery each loop will not end the entire function. Here is the code below. The purpose is, when a value in the array is not a number, it should stop all the function, not only the loop. But it turns out that it will only stop the loop and contiue the other logic below.

In C# or Java, the return word will stop the entire function. Is not desgined like this in JavaScript?

```
function testMehtod() {
        var itemIds = [];
        $("#confirmOrderItemContainer").find(":checkbox:checked").each(function (i, o) {
            itemIds[i] = $(o).attr('item-id');
            if (isNaN(itemIds[i])) {
                return false;
            } 
        });

        //other logic ...
}
```

Comment: A function can't exit the function it was called from. `.each()` can only stop its own loop, it can't return from `testMethod()`.

Comment: A `return` statement will only ever leave the current function by returning the specified value. In the given example it will end each anonymous function call in the jQuery-each method and will have no effect on the further execution within the (outer) function `testMehtod()`.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann It will also end the `.each()` loop because it treats `return false;` like a `break` statement in a loop.

Comment: Yes @Barmar, you are right! I forgot that that is one of those quirky extras jQuery built in to its `.each()` method - alongside with having the callback arguments in reverse order: `(index, element)` and not `(element, index)` like for `.map()`.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann To be fair, jQuery's `.map()` came before EcmaScript's version. So ES5 swapped the order.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you need to catch breaking the loop and return false too:

```
function testMehtod() {
    var itemIds = [];
    var ret = true; // our flag variable with default value - everything is good
    
    $("#confirmOrderItemContainer").find(":checkbox:checked").each(function (i, o) {
        itemIds[i] = $(o).attr('item-id');
        if (isNaN(itemIds[i])) { // not good
            ret = false; // let set flag about it
            return false; // break $.each loop
        } 
    });
    if (ret === false) { // not good? let's leave function
        return false;
    }

    //other logic ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is how I did it.